# Elements in list fading in at unexpected times

Tags: html, css

I am trying to load in separate elements in a list at different times.
The bird top left should be first, followed by the background and then the other elements.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF6f7.jpg

As you can see in this gif, the elements are fading in at times different than i expected. Anyone know why?

EDIT: If GIF does not load, the last element in the list loads first, and then the other elements load in order.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="anim">
    <li class="logo">
        <img src="imgs/bird.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="fullscreen-bg">
        <img class="fullscreen-bg__img" src="imgs/rockymountains.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="green1">
        <h1>ESTUDO</h1>
    </li>
    <li class="green2">
        <h1>ESTUDO E TRABALHO</h1>
    </li>
    <li class="green3">
        <h1>IMIGRAÇÃO</h1>
    </li>
    </div>
    <li class="red">
        <h1>SEU SONHO, NOSSA MISSÃO</h1>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
/* TEXT ANIMATIONS */

li {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadeIn 3.5s 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.anim li:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 1s }
.anim li:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 1.5s }
.anim li:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 2s }
.anim li:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 2.8s }
.anim li:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: 3.4s }

/*...*/

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
}

/* END TEXT ANIMATIONS */
```

From what i can tell all the children in the list are set properly. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **6 "li"** elements in your source but you have only set animation-delay for 1-5, that is why the 6th "li" do not have delay and will display first. Add in 1 more delay for that element will make it OK:

```
li {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadeIn 3.5s 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.anim li:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 1s }
.anim li:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 1.5s }
.anim li:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 2s }
.anim li:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 2.5s }
.anim li:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: 3s }
.anim li:nth-child(6) { animation-delay: 3.5s }

/*...*/

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice that! Thank you!